Get only first text value from inside of span as a tag manager variable
I've been trying to get the value under a span and use it as a variable inside tag manager with no luck. I've tried a few different scripts inside a custom javascript variable but constantly just get 'undefined' returned.
Below is the HTML where I'm trying to get the number of items in the users cart under the count class
<div class="site-main-menu__buttons-col">
                    <a class="link--icon-count">
                        <i class="icon--cart"></i>
                        <span class="is-hidden">Shopping cart</span>
                            <span class="count">1<span class="is-hidden"> items</span></span>
                    </a>
            </div>

I've tried a simple method like the below with no luck, I just get undefined as i mentioned already
function(){return document.getElementsByClassName("count").innerHTML;}

document.getElementsByClassName returns a list of matches because classes are not unique so you can get the first item by doing document.getElementsByClassName("count")[0].innerHTML.
However IDs seem to be a better fit to what you are trying to achieve because they are unique so you could just do document.getElementById("count").innerHTML and replace class="count" with id="count".

Thank you! That worked perfectly, but I'll take the advice and switch this to using an ID.

Also there is already a selector engine in GTM via the DOM type variable (which supports both ids and selectors), so there is usually no need to implement custom JS.
